# Occasionally getting Reference Error in Javascript console

Tags: javascript, sentry, referenceerror

I am occasionally getting different types of Reference errors logged in chrome console. 
For eg:

- require not defined
- Cookies not defined
- lozad not defined

The code is bundled in static-internal-bundle.js which is a combination of 7 different util files and minified using gulp-minify. 
This error is coming mainly when the url is hit from paid.braintree.com Ad urls and has utm_source, utm_medium and utm_campaign as query parameters.

This error is not consistent and mostly does not reoccur if the site is refreshed.

Also, it has been logged in sentry for all types of devices and Os for over 1.5k times in 6 months. Though it gets logged in console, nothing seems to break on the webpage. 
What could be the possible reasons for this type of error?

`<script type="text/javascript" src="https://static.pens.com/576801d7b3a368c06ba1944c07fe260b970da596/build/static-internal-bundle.js"></script>`

This is the script that gets added into the page in which the error is coming.

Answer (score 0):

I would add this as a comment but StackO won't let me without 50+ rep... I'll edit as needed.

Possibly the error could be in using "require" on the browser side, as browsers do not implement require

This sounds like a problem I have had with Babel, if it is being used I would try updating.

Comment: yes, babel is being used, babel-standalone.js. currently its at version 6.23.1
I have added the script-url in the question for reference.

Comment: Ok, try updating Babel - I believe Babel is on v7.9.x now. Hopefully that will solve or get a step closer to solving this issue. 
                  
Doing a quick search through the linked script I saw that require, Cookies, and lozad are all used; it could be that this script requires Lozad.js & js-Cookies to be pulled in as dependencies separately, though I'm not sure why it wouldn't recognize 'require'..